# Cannot make new class

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

Every time I try to make a new class I get a bunch of errors without even writing a single line of code.

register.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface register : UIViewController
@end
```

Gives errors:

> Expected identifier 
> Expected identifier or '('

register.m

```
#import "register.h"
@interface register ()
@end
@implementation register
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

@implementation register

> Expected identifier 
> Expected identifier or '('

`- (void)viewDidLoad` and `- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning` give:

> Missing context for method declaration

`@end` gives:

> @end must appear in an objective-c context

This happens every time I make a new class without writing any code at all.

Comment: This happens *every* time you make a new class? Even if you name it something other than `register`?

Comment: `register` is a keyword in C.  (Which is a good reason to follow C++/Objective-C coding conventions and always name classes with leading caps.)

Comment: thanks, i didnt even think to try another name!

Comment: your naming convention are quite poor. you should use better naming conventions, I really recommend you the Apple guidelines: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot name a class, variable, function, etc. with reserved keywords. Here is a list of Objective-C keywords: http://cupsofcocoa.com/2010/09/09/reserved-keywords/

To fix your problem, name your class something other than register (that's not a reserved keyword). You could even name it `Register` and it would compile.

Comment: Use the code convention. If you are subclassing UIViewController, name your class `RegisterViewController`